# Filter using positional arguments problem when deleting and adding a new doc to Firebase Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following piece of code in Python that first deletes a given doc from Firebase Firestore and then adds a new one.

```
def fr_delete_old_doc_add_new_doc_with_where(data_df, collection_name, where_field_name, where_field_value):

    db = firestore.client()

    data_df.fillna("-", inplace=True)

    col_ref = db.collection(collection_name)

    # First, delete previous document...
    # Note that several docs can be deleted if it where statement returns multiple results
    #docs = col_ref.where(where_field_name, u'==', where_field_value).stream()
    docs = col_ref.where(field_path=where_field_name, op_string="==", value=where_field_value).stream()
    deleted = 0

    for doc in docs:
        #print(f'Deleting doc {doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
        doc.reference.delete()
        deleted = deleted + 1
    print(deleted, " doc(s) deleted from the collection and the collection is now destroyed.")

    # Import data
    tmp = data_df.to_dict(orient='records')
    list(map(lambda x: col_ref.add(x), tmp))
    print("Saved ", data_df.shape[0], " records in Firestore collection < ", collection_name, " >" )
```

But this code is throwing the following warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_collection.py:290: UserWarning: Detected filter using positional arguments. Prefer using the 'filter' keyword argument instead.
> return query.where(field_path, op_string, value)

How can I get rid of this warning?